# What is the power order of the Straw Hats?

Tags: one-piece

I know it's quite difficult but I'd like to know the power level order between the Straw Hats. Currently I am assuming that the order is something like this:

1. Luffy
2. Zoro
3. Sanji

I'm aware from place 4 onward it gets really difficult, but maybe some hints exist. For example, Oda said that Usopp's current power equal that of Zoro before time skip. That would be a good example of a great hint.

Some measurements could be the opponents they have faced, their individual power, devil fruits and for those that have it, their haki.

Comment: Generally speaking, the strongest three are usually considered to be zoro, sanji, and luffy while nami, ussop, and chopper are considered the weakest three.  Beyond this, however, it is speculation which is inappropriate for this site.

Comment: For the close votes. This is actually a question that can be answered in universe, using the [doriki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Doriki) system. Or even their bounties.

Comment: Exactly. There several ways to measure it. Also hints like which straw hats develop haki, comments from the author [what I said about Usopp...]

Comment: @Dimitrimx I don't like diagreeing with you but doriki only indicates strength in a very limited way (Rokushiki). We also don't know the doriki for any strawhats.  Bounties don't indicate fighting strength almost at all. They only indicate threat to WG.

Comment: @kaine It does still point out,  that in a canonical way we can determine how their in-universe government judges their strength. And there are several others. Combined these values may actually reflect the strength of the individual members quite accurately. Non the less, limited as it may be, this question can be answered perfectly in a non opinion based answer. All though I do agree, the question could use some slight rephrasing in the 3th paragraph to also reflect it as a non-opinion based question.

Comment: @Dimitrimx The question is answerable but not of great quality because the answer will ALWAYS be primarily opinion based even if it tries to use canonical measurements. Luffy a 100M bounty defeats someone which the author states is worth 500m. Sogeking has less bounty than Franky but God Ussop has twice as much? There are simply too many variables to sort out a completely Non-opinion based list of power. Compare it to the strength order of Avengers or Justice League if you will. Drawing on the parallels, Who is stronger Cap or Iron Man? Martian Manhunter or Superman? and so on...

Comment: well, Oda did say Usopp has been and will be the weakest in strawhats but never stated the rest of the crew strength order

Comment: I've voted to close as well because I think the issue is defining strength. Is it raw power? That would be a poor definition for One Piece as we also have to take into account Devil Fruits and Haki. But then, we know some DF are better against some than others. So it may be possible than A > B, B > C and C > A. How would be the power order is that case? Also, A could defeat B when B is in a bad day, but does that truly mean A > B? HxH makes a great job explaining this in the Chimera Ants. In the end, it all comes down to a judgement call.

Comment: As an example, there are tons of people Enel could have defeated that pre-timeskip Luffy would not be able to. What's the power order in that case?

Comment: This post is part of a discussion on [meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/should-this-question-be-left-open-or-is-it-opinion-based)

Comment: During Franky's arc, Luffy never beat him, they just called it a draw, so I always thought Franky was on par with Luffy, even if he's never in the spotlight for fighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is after the dressrosa arc:

The bounties are a good representative of the strength of each member of the strawhat crew.

The only odd ones are Sanji, Usopp and Chopper.

Chopper because he is viewed as a pet instead of a full member
Sanji because he didn't participate that much and Usopp because he was said to be the one who instigated everything but that was wrong.

So for power range according to posters (with dismissing odd things):

1. Luffy
2. Zoro
3. Sanji
4. Nico Robin
5. Franky
6. Brooke
7. Usopp
8. Chopper
9. Nami

Usopp, Chopper and Nami are also called the weak trio so saying those three are the weakest is a pretty good assumption.

[image: Straw Hats Wanted Posters]

Comment: you mean weak trio?

Comment: Basing this off of the wanted posters is not a really good idea, as for example chopper is considered a pet and thus he doesn't get a reputation as high as the others. IMO chopper is stronger than Usopp and Brooke